# How to Get the old partition table

Tags: partitioning

I have re-installed Ubuntu from 16.04LTS 64 bit to 14.04LTS 64 bit. I have lost the previous partitions (NTFS) and now, Ubuntu recognises everything as single partition.

Can some one advice the recovery steps to get the old partition table?

Comment: Let me check, If it is then I will remove my question.

Comment: @UDID: You can't remove questions, not even your own.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I mean i will delete. But the solution of the perticular question is seems complected for me.

Comment: @UDID: Same. You can't delete questions either. Only moderators or a vote by reviewers with the pertaining privilege (tied to their reputation points) can delete questions.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Ya got it. :)